# window.open popup textfield on focus when popping up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a page that opens a pop up

```
<script>
var popup = window.open('forms/trucksform.php');
popup.moveTo(0,0);
popup.resizeTo(318,340);
popup.focus();
popup.moveBy(500,200);
</script>
```

how can i focus on the textfield inside this popup

```
   <div class="mainform">
        <form name="addtrucks" id="addtrucks" method="POST" action="<?php echo  $editFormAction; ?>">
            <label>Truck Plate Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="truck_plate_no" id="truck_plate_no" />
            <br/>
            <input name="button" type="submit" id="button" onclick="MM_validateForm('truck_plate_no','','R');return document.MM_returnValue"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="add" />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 ways:
From the parent page you can get access to popup window:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var popup = window.open('trucksform.php');
popup.onload = function() {
    popup.document.getElementById("truck_plate_no").focus();
};
popup.moveTo(0,0);
popup.resizeTo(318,340);
popup.focus();
popup.moveBy(500,200);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or add initial state to popup (this way better, because you will have reference to element on same page):

```
 <div class="mainform">
        <form name="addtrucks" id="addtrucks" method="POST" action="<?php echo  $editFormAction; ?>">
            <label>Truck Plate Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="truck_plate_no" id="truck_plate_no" />
            <br/>
            <input name="button" type="submit" id="button" onclick="MM_validateForm('truck_plate_no','','R');return document.MM_returnValue"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="add" />
        </form>
    </div>
<script>
   document.getElementById("truck_plate_no").focus();   
</script>
```

**Update for Chrome:**
It look as manipulation with popup window is blocking some UI functions. You can add to text input attribute `autofocus="autofocus"` in popup. To remove manipulation with popup window use parameters for `open`:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var popup = window.open('trucksform.php', 'myWindowName', 'left=200,top=500,width=318,height=340');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$("#truck_plate_no").focus();
```

Comment: where should i put this? on the first page, or the pop up page?

Comment: i am using chrome and i read alot right now on forums that chrome seems to be blocking this.